# Send notification to all developers when a release fails in VSTS (prev. VSO)

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS), previously known as Visual Studio Online (VSO) to build a Continuous Delivery pipeline. My goal is to follow as close as possible the [Continuous Delivery](http://martinfowler.com/books/continuousDelivery.html) book from Jez Humble and David Farley.

I would like that when a stage (named Environment in VSTS) fails, a notification (an email) is sent to **every developers involved in this release**. This notification would say either :

- You broke the stage (Regression)
- The stage was already broken (Failed)
- You fixed the stage. (Fixed)

Currently, only the person who created the release manually (or by pushing the commit which triggered the build and after that the release) will receive this email and without the information I want.

I've played a little bit with VSTS API, and can get the associated commits (and the developers email) for a given build (but not for a given release) :

```bsh
$token = "vsts token"
$endpoint = "https://acme.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_apis/build/builds/42/changes?api-version=2.0"

$b64creds = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($token):a"))
$changes = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization="Basic $b64creds"} $endpoint

$changes.value | ForEach-Object { $_.author.uniqueName }
```

I've seen that in VSTS interface, you can see which commits were added between 2 releases. It's very close of what I want even if I didn't found this information in the API. But even with this information, a same release definition is used for all branches of my project, so for example Release-26 will be a feature branch and Release-27 will be develop. It doesn't make sense to compare these 2 releases.

I know that I can get the build ID in a release stage from the environment variable, and after that use my script above and create a PowerShell Task or a Webservice plugged on VSTS. But it will only work if a release is triggered for each build, which is not always the case.

**Do you know a (better) way to send this notifications with VSTS ?**
And do I use the right tool for that sort of things ?

Comment: Hopefully we will see release monitoring implemented in Catlight one day. It does a pretty good job alerting the team about VSTS build status, but release tracking is not there - http://catlight.helprace.com/i17-add-support-to-release-status

Answer (score 0):

You can only send the email alert to "Environment owner" & "Release creator" and there isn't any way to customize the content in the email alert for now, you can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

Rest API is a good tool to get these information. But you mentioned that you are using the same release definition for all branches. This does not make sense. Different branches refer to different version of your project, why do you deploy all of them in one release pipeline? If you configure your workflow to one release definition per branch, the resolution would be more easy. You just need to get the Build ID for previous release, and then get the changes after that build. And you can also add a powershell task to create a lable/tag for TFVC/Git repositories for current release version so that you can get the changes between the labels/tags.

Comment: _Different branches refer to different version of your project, why do you deploy all of them in one release pipeline?_

Sure, I totally agree, but we want to have a git workflow as described in the article ["A successful git branching model"](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

And it involves the creation of a lot of branches. And that's the only way I know to automatically build this branches. I didn't found an option like the multibranch pipeline in jenkins. It would be really complicated and counterproductive to handle all this branches by hand.

Comment: @Q.Dufour You can have a lot of branches during the development, but in usual, the process is to merge all the changes back to the release or master branch when the code in other branches is stable and ready to release. Then you can build and deploy the code in the release or master branch. And when you create build definition in VSTS with Git repository, you can only select one branch for one build definition. But you mentioned your release definition is for all branches, do you link the release definition to server build definitions?

Comment: Yes, we merge all our feature branches in develop/master. But before merging, we want to check that our whole pipeline is not broken, and we use Release Management to build this pipeline. It includes our integration tests, UI tests, performance tests, deployment on QA and its validation, etc. So we automatically trigger a release for every build on every branch, as we want to have a feedback on every code change as soon as possible. Might be the problem...

Comment: @Q.Dufour Verify the code change on every branch does make sense. But if you set all of them linked to one release definition, does it means the build for all branches will be deployed and tested when the release is only triggered by one branch?

Comment: Well, good question. With the new jenkins pipeline, you can add conditional stages, on the git branch for example. In VSTS, we have an environment variable named `RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_#NAME#_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` wich contains the source branch for the artifact. In our final stage "push to production", we can add a condition on this variable. But I'm feeling that I'm trying to do the wrong thing with VSTS, as we want to do more than deploying on a specific environment. More like the [pipeline article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery#Deployment_pipeline)